# Ensembling the 10-fold models

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, ensemble-learning

I can ensemble the predictions from 10-folds and calculate final accuracy.

However, when I save the model as in the following code, it just saves a model from 1-fold. 
There are such 10 models.

In the world of machine learning, is there something like Ensembling/Combining/Aggregating the 10-fold models?

I want to make the final model from 10 models (obtained from 10-folds) so as to use it for predicting with new data.

Is it possible?

```
ypred_all = np.ones((y.shape))
EnsembledModel = []
kfolds = KFold(n_splits=10) 
for train, test in kf.split(x):
   train_x = features[train]
   train_y = labels[train]
   test_x = features[test]
   test_y = labels[test]
   model = clf.fit(train_x, train_y)  

   dump(model, 'model.joblib') 

   EnsembledModel.append (model)  ##???

   ypred = model.predict(test_x)
   ypred_all[test] = ypred


final_accuracy =  accuracy_score(y, ypred_all)


final_model = ...EnsembledModel ##??

final_predict = final_model.predict(x_new)
```

Comment: How do you calculate the final accuracy from the 10 estimators? Do you average individual preditions and then calculate accuracy on final predictions or first calculate accuracy on each and then average all accuracies to get final?

Comment: If doing first way, then `VotingClassifier` exists for this very reason: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.VotingClassifier.html. If second, then how will you use the 10 models on new data to make predictions?

Comment: `final_accuracy =  accuracy_score(y, ypred_all)` or average of 10s `accuracy_score(test_y, ypred)`

Comment: See this works, because in your `y_pred_all` you will only have a single value for each of the sample present in test (because you used K-Fold, each sample will be in test exactly once). I am asking about new data. For a single new sample, you will have 10 outputs, how will you then make a final single prediction output for that single sample

Comment: in this i would like to use `average`

Comment: What do you mean by average here? Average of probabilities to find a single probability and if that probability > threshold, then assign a class or else assign another?? How many classes do you have?

Comment: This is going to ensembling `predictions`. I want to `ensemble` 10 models themselves. `VotingClassifier` would ensemble `classifiers` and `predictions`.

Comment: Not clear. Can you give an example of what do you want to achieve? During training and during testing?

Comment: please see my edit

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203607/discussion-between-vivek-kumar-and-mk1).

Comment: You need to save models with different names for each fold - currently you replace saved model on each fold.

Comment: @AndreyLukyanenko Then, how can i fuse 10 saved models?

Comment: Make predictions by each model and take mean of the result.

Answer (score 2):

Common misconception: k-fold is only to validate the model, not its parameters.

The workflow is:

1. The dataset is split into train and test.
2. Develop features and reason about applicable algorithms
3. For promising combinations of feature set and algorithms (OLS, SVM, NN, etc), train on a subset of the train set - this is where you use k folds. Use average performance as a metric to this model, i.e. the combination of features and the algorithm. As a result of this step you select the best model (but not parameters).
4. Train the selected model on the whole train set. This will improve the model a bit because you have a bit more data. As a result of this step you get model parameters.
5. Evaluate final performance on the test set.

Note: the terminology is different. Some people call test set the holdout, some use the same terms for cross-validation sets. Also, for single use disposable one-shot models you might want completely skip steps 1 and 5.

The answer to your question is step 4: **once you found the best model, you train on the whole train set.**

**UPD:**
In some cases, different parts of your dataset are better addressed with different models. In some cases, you might even use the same model on different partitions of your dataset, e.g. to approximate a polinomial with a set of linear functions. Combination of multiple models then will give you an ensemble. If folds are random, however, it doesn't make much sense.

Comment: yes, i agree your approach. However, is not there another approach for fusing models themselves? How about it? https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/classreg.learning.partition.regressionpartitionedmodel-class.html

Comment: how can i combine multiple models as an ensemble?

Comment: @mk1 the point of this answer is: in this case, you don't. Once you selected the best model, you just train one model on the whole training set, without any folding.